# formular una oración uniendo dos oraciones enpython

Tags: python

Tengo un ejercicio en el cual no he logrado entender como resolverlo, no he comprendido como elaborar un algoritmo en python que pueda resolverlo. Por favor quien pueda explicar como resolverlo, agradecería mucho!!

Escriba una función que reciba por parámetro dos oraciones con el mismo número de palabras, por ejemplo cadena1 y cadena2, y retorne una tercera cadena con las palabras de cadena1 y cadena2 intercaladas. La frase resultante comienza con la primera palabra de cadena1, continúa con la primera palabra de la cadena2 y así sucesivamente. Por ejemplo, si cadena1 es “La casa está cerca río” y la cadena2 es “linda no muy del grande”, se obtendría la oración: “La linda casa no está muy cerca del río grande”. Tome en consideración que después de cada palabra proveniente de alguna de las dos cadenas debe ingresarse un espacio en blanco. Sin embargo, tenga cuidado de no incluir un espacio al final. USANDO BUCLES FOR O WHILE!!

con un ejemplo en internet trate de hacer y tengo esto:

```
a = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
b = input("Ingrese otra oracion: ")

max_list = max(len(a), len(b)) 
check_size = lambda list, max: list + [''] * max if len(list) < max else list

a = check_size(a, max_list) 
# //a = ["hola", "cómo", "estado", ""] 
b = check_size(b, max_list) 
# //b = ["paz,", "has", "hoy?", ":)"] 

" ".join([item for sublist in zip(a, b) for item in sublist if item != ""])
```

Comment: podrías agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: ya lo agregue, espero puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se vale usar cualquier cosa, puedes evitar complicarte cual es la oración con más palabras, usando [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) la cual intercala los elementos entre 2 listas. Si una tiene más elementos que otra, los omitirá.

```
>>> a = "Esta una textosobrante"
>>> b = "es prueba"
>>> paso1 = zip(a.split(' '), b.split(' '))
>>> print(list(paso1))
[('Esta', 'es'), ('una', 'prueba')]
>>> paso2 = [' '.join(paso1)]
>>> print(paso2)
['Esta es', 'una prueba']
>>> paso3 = ' '.join(paso2)
>>> print(paso3)
Esta es una prueba
```

Con lo anterior, puedes hacer una función de una sola línea:

```
return ' '.join([' '.join(x) for x in zip(a.split(' '), b.split(' '))])
```

Ok, como es con for o while, aquí una versión usando listas. Se utiliza la longitud de la lista con menos palabras para iterar en ambas.

```
def intercalar(a, b):
    l1 = a.split(' ')
    l2 = b.split(' ')
    size1 = len(l1)
    size2 = len(l2)
    menor = size1 if size1 <= size2 else size2
    res = []
    i = 0
    while i < menor:
        res.append(l1[i])
        res.append(l2[i])
        i += 1
    return ' '.join(res)
```

El mismo caso anterior, pero usando operaciones de cadenas. Notar que la cadena queda con un espacio en blanco al final, por eso se retorna `[:-1]` para eliminarlo

```
def intercalar(a, b):
    l1 = a.split(' ')
    l2 = b.split(' ')
    size1 = len(l1)
    size2 = len(l2)
    menor = size1 if size1 <= size2 else size2
    res = ' '
    i = 0
    while i < menor:
        res = f'{res}{l1[i]} {l2[i]} '
        i += 1
    return res[:-1]
```

Comment: Se me olvido decir, que se debe usar ciclos, sea for o while

Comment: Ok, coloqué 2 versiones más con ciclo while @JonhJames

Comment: Eres un crack, gracias. Tener dos visiones hacia la misma solución da entender muy bien las cosas, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 2):

No sé si necesitas utilizar ciclos en todo, pero en caso solo tengas que usar los ciclos en una parte puedes ahorrarte un poco de código.

Para "simular" la función `zip` he creado una función que usa un ciclo `for` para ir agregando de forma intercalada las palabras de la oración.

```py
def my_zip(a,b):
    a = a.split()
    b = b.split()

    for i in range(0,len(a)+len(b),2):
        n = i if i==0 else i//2
        b.insert(i,a[n])
    return b
```

Aquí convertimos cada argumento (solo strings) a una lista, posteriormente iteramos en un rango que será la longitud final pero vamos de 2 en 2, dentro del `for` vamos a ir añadiendo a la lista `b` los elementos de la lista `a` y finalmente retornamos la lista `b`.

Ahora lo única que tenemos que hacer es pedir los datos, usar la función y unir el resultado, para el cual necesitaremos otro `for`.

```py
a = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
b = input("Ingrese otra oracion: ")

final = ""
for frase in my_zip(a,b):
    final+=f"{frase} "
print(final)
```

Si se te permite,puedes ahorrarte el `for` y usar el método `join` así `print(" ".join(my_zip(a,b)))`

y todo esto nos dará como resultado:

```
Ingrese una oracion: La casa está cerca río
Ingrese otra oracion: linda no muy del grande
La linda casa no está muy cerca del río grande
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendí bien y aprendí. Voy aplicarlo.

Comment: de nada, me alegra que hayas aprendido ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Una solución simple:

```
ora1 = "la mona jacinta".split()
ora2 = "se ha puesto".split()

b = []
for i in range(len(ora1)):
    b.extend([ora1[i], ora2[i]])
final = ' '.join(b)
```

Con `split` convierto ambas oraciones en listas de palabras. Como ambas listas tienen el mismo largo, las puedo recorrer con un `for` y en cada iteración agregar dos elementos (uno de cada lista).

Para agregar usamos `extend` en lugar de `append`. La diferencia es que `extend` recibe un lista y agrega sus elementos (no la lista).

#### Demo

```
ora1 = "la jacinta ha".split()
ora2 = "mona se puesto".split()

b = []
for i in range(len(ora1)):
    b.extend([ora1[i], ora2[i]])
final = ' '.join(b)
print(final)
```

produce:

```
la mona jacinta se ha puesto

Process finished with exit code 0
```